# Bootstrap Modal inside ui-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router, bootstrap-modal

I am using Angular ui-router and Bootstrap Modal and this is the output of my code:

[image]

As you can see, the backdrop/shadow of the modal only applies to the state. My current code is:

**Index.html**

```
<!-- title, header and everything here -->
<div class="panel-body">
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
<!-- JS and everything here -->
```

**Routes / app.js**

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider

    .state('products', {
        url: '/products',
        templateUrl: 'templates/products.html',
        controller: 'ProductController'
    })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');
});
```

**products.html**

```
<div ng-controller="ProductController">
<button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addProduct"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Product</button>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product Code</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="p in products | orderBy:'product_name' |filter:searchProduct" ng-class="{'qtyLess' : p.product_quantity <= 10}">
                <td>{{p.product_code}}</td>
                <td>{{p.product_name}}</td>
                <td>{{p.product_quantity}}</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-raised" ng-click="viewProduct(p.product_id)">View</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
   <!-- Add Product Modal -->
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="addProduct" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h2 class="modal-title">Add Product</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="horizontal-form">
                        <form class="form-horizontal">
                            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="color: #e51c23">Product Code</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" ng-model="productData.product_code" class="form-control" id="name">
                            </div>
                            <label for="company" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="color: #e51c23">Product Name</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" ng-model="productData.product_name" class="form-control" id="company">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" ng-click="addProduct()" class="btn btn-raised btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
```

What I wanted to happen is to do what it should be doing; to be on top of everything. So this is how should it look like:

[image]

As you can see, the backdrop applies to the whole page. This is what I wanted to happen.

So my first fix is to put all the modals from `products.html` to `index.html` and instead of using `$scope` for the datas, I used `$rootScope`. The trick works though on every page I have multiple modals and I don't want to put it all in the `index.html` because the code will look untidy and I have to change everything from `$scope` to `$rootScope`.

Is there an easier way to fix this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you open the modal, I mean with what options?

Comment: @ManuelObregozo I updated my post and added some code

Comment: Last request, could you please add the .open method from your controller. The one you use to open the model, I just wanted to see the options.

But the best option is :
Put the html of your modal in an external file. And then when calling the modal specify that url.

Comment: @ManuelObregozo I don't have the .open method in my controller as you can see the button data-target="#addProduct" and the modal is also there. Even if I use ng-click and .open method in my controller it outputs the same.

Comment: I see, my bad. The thing is if you attach the modal to that view(html) the class .fade.in which add the opacity will be applied to parent <div> of where you define the modal html.

Comment: @ManuelObregozo Yes and that's the problem I'm facing now. Don't want to put all of my modals in the index file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131058/discussion-between-manuel-obregozo-and-fewflyby).

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the modal as an external File. Otherwise if you attach the modal to that view(html) the class .fade.in which add the opacity will be applied to parent  of where you define the modal html.

Inside your controller ProductController, you will have something like this:

```
$uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html'
    });
```

Where myModalContent.html will be the same code you have in here:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addProduct" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h2 class="modal-title">Add Product</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="horizontal-form">
                        <form class="form-horizontal">
                            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="color: #e51c23">Product Code</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" ng-model="productData.product_code" class="form-control" id="name">
                            </div>
                            <label for="company" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="color: #e51c23">Product Name</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" ng-model="productData.product_name" class="form-control" id="company">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" ng-click="addProduct()" class="btn btn-raised btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
```

Check this plunker with an example of how you could resolve this:
https://plnkr.co/edit/LgokUqXxCg1shegBy2GZ?p=preview